# GDAL Raster plugin doesn't work

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, oracle-dbms

I am connected to Oracle, using QGIS and can see the vector data table.

I am trying to use the GDAL Raster plugin to view raster data, in QGIS.
When I click on the Oracle GeoRaster plugin, get a cannot connect error.

The plugin is installed as shown in the image.
[image: GeoRaster Plugin]

I have pointed the GDal Raster settings to both paths below. In case that was the issue

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.16.0\bin\gdalplugins
C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.16.0\apps\qgis\qtplugins
```

[image: Tool Settings]

Comment: your question seems to have been truncated - please edit to add the missing information.

Comment: Hi                                                                                                                            I updated the posting..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is just a problem with your GDAL installation. You may need to do some more checks:

1) Are you able to use GDAL from the command line ? Does the following work ?

```
gdalinfo --version
```

2) Does your gdal installation include the proper georaster plugin ? Does it appear in the following list ?

```
gdalindo --formats
```

3) Can you check a raster stored in Oracle ? Something like this:

```
gdalinfo georaster:scott/tiger@localhost:1521/orcl121,us_rasters,georaster
```

4) Are you able to use GDAL from QGIS for reading other data - like plain files ?